# Block edit distance with Swapping only

Tags: string, algorithm, edit-distance, string-metric

Suppose I have distinct alphabets `∑={a1,a2,...,an}`. I also have two permutations of these alphabets, let's call them `A,B`. How can I find the Edit distance between `A` and `B` with block edit operations allowed?

To make it clearer, an example would be `∑={a,b,c,d}`. Two possible permutations are `A=abcd`,`B=dabc`. The edit distance here would be 1 because we can swap the block `abc` with `d` to get one string to the other.

Clearly, there won't be any deletions/insertions in this form of the problem, it will purely be swaps since the two strings are permutations of the same letters.

Now I know that the original edit-block problem with all operations is NP-Hard, however, would the restriction of only block swaps perhaps make this solvable in polynomial time? Most text I've read don't address this version and instead address variations of the original problem. Any help would be appreciated.